# using a 32bit ARM processor to write 64bit atomic operation in assembly in user mode in a multithreaded system (is it possible?)

Tags: assembly, arm, atomic, 32bit-64bit

I wanted to write assembly language for an atomic64bit read/write function for a multithreaded OS, however the processor I am using is 32bit (AM574x, AM576x, Sitara Processors, Cortex A15 using the ARMv7-A architecture) and it is running in user mode and it needs to stay in user mode (means disable interrupt won't work - CPSID I). In assembly is there a way to do this?

Comment: Which variant of the ARM architecture are you programming for?

Comment: @fuz AM574x/AM576x

Comment: That's a Cortex A15 using the ARMv7-A architecture.

Comment: Do you need any consistency/memory ordering guarantees?

Comment: @fuz nop i think if the 64bit data is not top 32bit from thread 1 and bottom 32bit from thread 2 its good enough.

Comment: Note also that disabling interrupts is generally not sufficient for a 64 bit memory access to be atomic.  This is because the access can be split into multiple accesses and an intermediate state could be observed e.g. by other threads or peripherals.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Refer to section A3.4 “Synchronization and semaphores” of the *ARM Architecture Reference Manual Armv7-A and ARMv7-R Edition* (DDI 0406C).

This boils down to using the `ldrexd` and `strexd` instructions in a loop:

```
        @ assuming r0 holds the address, r1:r2 holds the datum to be stored
again:  ldrexd r3, r4, [r0]      @ retrieve old value, tag memory
        strexd r3, r1, r2, [r0]  @ attempt to store
        cmp    r3, #0            @ did the store succeed?
        bne    again
```

The `ldrexd` instruction is required to tag the memory for the exclusive store.  It cannot be eliminated.  You must perform this operation in a loop as it can spuriously fail.

Comment: is it possible if we need data consistency ?

Comment: @user1998844 If you need memory ordering guarantees, issue a suitable set of barriers before and/or after the loop.

Comment: @user1998844: Look at how GCC and/or clang compile something like C++ `std::atomic<uint64_t> shared;` with `shared.exchange(foo, std::memory_order_release)` or other memory orders, with an appropriate `-mcpu=` option for you CPU.  https://godbolt.org/z/nYb7zMnb8.  And/or see https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~pes20/cpp/cpp0xmappings.html

Comment: @fuz hey will strexd always return 1 ?

Comment: @user1998844 As I said in my answer, no.  It may spuriously fail.  This is why a loop is required.

Comment: @fuz do you know why will it fails ? when I  run with debugger I saw it fails but when I run without a debugger I went thru on the 1st try.

Comment: @user1998844 It can fail spuriously (i.e. for no apparent reason).  It can fail because an interrupt occurs between the `ldrexd` and the `strexd`.  It can fail because some other thread altered memory in the same region the `ldrexd` instruction tagged.  It can fail because the process was moved to a different core between the `ldrexd` and the `strexd`.  There are many possible reasons.  It will however eventually succeed.

Comment: @fuz hi sorry to bother you again: So if any thread comes in between ldrexd and strexd , the store will return 1 right? so its means i can put a addition instruction in-between to make a atomic add right ?

Comment: @user1998844 Yes, correct.  `ldrexd` tags the address you loaded from.  This tag is violated if any other thread tries to write memory in the same region (or for other reasons).  `strexd` only succeeds if the tag is still valid.  This allows you to implement pretty much any atomic operation you want.  Refer to the Architecture Reference Manual for details.

Comment: @fuz "The value of a in this assignment is implementation defined, between a minimum value of 3 and a maximum value of 11. For example, in an implementation where a is 4, a successful LDREX of address 0x000341B4 gives a tag value of bits[31:4] of the address, giving 0x000341B. This means that the four words of memory from 0x000341B0 to 0x000341BF are tagged for exclusive access." 
it means that minimum tag size is 64bit right? 
because Tagged_address = Memory_address[31:3]